Command \affil already defined authblk.sty
I'm using the lipics-v2021 template  and I don't know how to fix the \affil already defined error.
\documentclass[a4paper,UKenglish,cleveref, autoref, thm-restate]{lipics-v2021} 

\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,mathrsfs} \usepackage{graphicx} \usepackage{epsfig} \usepackage{authblk}

\EventShortTitle{STACS 2024} \EventAcronym{STACS} \EventYear{2024}

\title{adagdsfafvdasfd} \author{Anonymous Authors} \keywords{Approximation Algorithms} \ccsdesc[100]{Theory of computation~Design and analysis of algorithms}

\authorrunning{Annonymous} \date{} \begin{document}

\maketitle \thispagestyle{empty} \begin{abstract} sdfg \end{abstract} \section{Introduction} fagdsfg \end{document}


Just add \let\affil\relax before \usepackage{authblk} to allow it to redefine it.

Why do load the package with a so special class? It probably has its own commands. Unrelated but do not load epsfig that is outdated since more than 20 years.

In small instances like this, you can declare the "offending" command as undeclared via
\let\affil\relax

before loading the package. Since you didn't show your need for adding authblk, there seems to be no additional benefit. In fact, the lipics-v2021 template already provides author and affiliation setting.

TL;DR
lipics-v2021 is a specialized class for the ”Leibniz International Proceedings in Informatics“ by Dagstuhl Publishing. Follow the guidelines and don't try to modify the layout.
How to input author information in lipics-v2021
The sample paper shows this code for an author (reformatted for clarity)
% TODO mandatory, please use full name; only 1 author per \author macro;
% first two parameters are mandatory, other parameters can be empty.
% Please provide at least the name of the affiliation and the country.
% The full address is optional
\author{John Q. Public}
  {Dummy University Computing Laboratory,
    [optional: Address], Country
    \and My second affiliation, Country
    \and \url{http://www.myhomepage.edu}}
  {johnqpublic@dummyuni.org}
  {https://orcid.org/0000-0002-1825-0097}
  {(Optional) author-specific funding acknowledgements}

The \author command takes five arguments: the first one is the author's name; the second one is the affiliation; the third is the author's email address; the fourth is the ORCID address; the fifth is for notes.
The third, fourth and fifth arguments can be left empty if the information isn't to be provided.
Comments
The publisher wants all papers in their proceedings volumes to have a homogenous layout and the class provides its own method for inserting author information and print it.
Using authblk for the job would (even without the command name conflict) disrupt the homogeneity and your paper would probably be sent back for changes, if not outright rejected.
